# Unknown Angular Routing Issue

Tags: angular

I was just trying to learn myself some Angular.
I learned that you have to use the routerLink directive in order for Angular to change routes without the page refreshing.
However, I have some strange behavior.
In the code below, you can see I structured all of my navigation links in the same way. But the home route that's wrapped around my logo (the bottom one) always causes the page to refresh when I click it.
Is it maybe because of the image?

```
 <nav>
    <div id="container">
      <ul class="{{ menuIsVisible ? 'visible' : null }}">
        <ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-route [ngForOf]="routes">
          <ng-template [ngIf]="i !== placeLogo" [ngIfElse]="withLogo">
            <li>
              <a
                class="{{ active === route.path ? 'active' : null }} {{
                  hovered === route.path ? 'hovered' : null
                }}"
                (click)="handleClick($event)"
                (mouseover)="handleHover($event)"
                (mouseleave)="resetHover()"
                [routerLink]="route.path"
                >{{ route.path === "" ? "home" : route.path }}</a
              >
            </li>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #withLogo>
            <li>
              <a
                class="{{ active === route.path ? 'active' : null }} {{
                  hovered === route.path ? 'hovered' : null
                }}"
                (click)="handleClick($event)"
                (mouseover)="handleHover($event)"
                (mouseleave)="resetHover()"
                [routerLink]="route.path"
                >{{ route.path === "" ? "Home" : route.path }}</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="logo" [routerLink]="''" (click)="handleClick($event)"
                ><img
                  src="assets/images/logo-white.svg"
                  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                  alt="logo"
              /></a>
            </li>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

These are my routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: "skills", component: SkillsComponent },
  { path: "experience", component: ExperienceComponent },
  { path: "contact", component: ContactComponent }
];
```

Comment: Are you have some errors in console?

Comment: Could you post the routes defined in the associated js file?

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey I added the routes as you asked, the home route works perfectly for the navigation item where I added the route path in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Please specify link for **routerlink** for image

```
<li>
  <a class="logo" [routerLink]="''" (click)="handleClick($event)">
    <img src="assets/images/logo-white.svg" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" alt="logo" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should specify `'/'` as the `[routerLink]` value. If you look at the documentation for `routerLink`: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description

You will see the following:

> If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.

I believe what's happening is that the empty value is causing it to reload the current route.

Comment: I've tried it like this "''", like this "'/'", like this "['']" and like this "['/']", and nothing works, the strange thing is, I added the home route as a nav item in the for loop too, and there it works just fine